# Python multiprocessing and sockets not being closed

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, process, multiprocessing

I'm experiencing an odd  behaviour when using multiprocessing and socket on Python. I'm dealing with a piece of code similar that the one I'm posting below (I've simplified things a lot trying to be naive).

The code spawns three processes: one process does nothing, another process launches the third one, that will be listening on a socket. If I terminate the "listener" process, the socket still remains open (I can see it there with a netstat).

- If I remove (or stop) the "DoNothing" process, this works.
- If I switch everything to threading.Thread, this works, but
- If I leave the DoNothing as a Process and switch the Server and Launcher to threading.Thread, the problem persists.

Does anyone have any hint why the socket is still opened? Is there any problem dealing with multiprocessing and sockets?

I'm using python 2.6.6 running on Linux.

Thank you very much,
Alvaro.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Event

import socket

class Server(Process):
    def __init__(self, port):
        super(Server, self).__init__()

        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.s.bind(("127.0.0.1",port))
        self.s.listen(1)
        self.s.settimeout(10)
        self.is_stop = Event()
        self.is_stop.clear()

    def run(self):
        while not self.is_stop.is_set():
            print "Server: running (pid %s)" % self.pid 
            time.sleep(1)
        print "Server: exiting"

    def stop(self):
        self.is_stop.set()
        self.s.close()

class Launcher(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Launcher, self).__init__()
        self.srv = Server(9999)
        self.srv.start()

    def run(self):
        print "Launcher pid %s" % self.pid
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)

    def stop(self):
        print "Launcher: I'm stopping the server"
        self.srv.stop()
        self.srv.terminate()
        self.srv.join()
        print "Launcher: server stopped"

class DoNothing(Process):
    def __init__(self):                
        super(DoNothing, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)


l = Launcher()
l.start()

dn = DoNothing()
dn.start()

time.sleep(2)

print " Stop launcher "
l.stop()

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

**EDIT:**

Relevant `netstat -lnp` output:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9999          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7183/python
```

I've noticed that the pid shown in netstat changes from the parent process (when the process Server is running) to the Launcher's one (when the server is stopped).

Comment: What is the relevant line of netstat output?

Comment: I've updated the original posting with it (I totally forgot!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix the immediate problem (of the socket not shutting down), add `self.s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)`  to the `Server.stop` method:

```
def stop(self):
    self.is_stop.set()
    self.s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR) 
    self.s.close()
```

Comment: Why is shutdown necessary? According to https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html, in most cases, `close` is sufficient over `shutdown`. What makes this case special?

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert on the `multiprocessing` package, but it would appear that the `Process` constructor is called in the context of the **parent process** (i.e. before the [fork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28operating_system%29)). If that's the case, then it follows that it is the topmost process in your hierarchy that does the `bind`. The child processes probably inherit the socket.

What happens if you move everything that deals with `self.s` (`bind` et al) into `Server.run`?

Comment: Thank you for your hint. This behaviour (i.e. the socket being created on the parent process) is not present in the original script (I've simplified a lot, and rewrote it quickly).The only thing that changes is the process owning the socket, but the behaviour continues the same.